# How to change dxf layer color in java using jdxf library?

Tags: java, dxf

I have a java code generating dxf files, I am using jdxf library. Almost everything works fine with it, there is only one thing I could not figure out. When I'm adding a new Layer, I wish to do it with a new color so that all entities I draw under this new layer shall have a "ByLayer" color, which would be this new color I specify.
I can only achieve that the entities shall have the color I specify, but their layer's default color would still be black/white. Here is my DXFHandler object:

```
public class DXFHandler {
//https://jsevy.com/wordpress/index.php/java-and-android/jdxf-java-dxf-library/

DXFGraphics graphics;
DXFDocument dXFDocument;
int mirrorY, mirrorX;

public DXFHandler() {
    dXFDocument = new DXFDocument();
    dXFDocument.setUnits(4);//set units to mm
    dXFDocument.setPrecisionDigits(1);//set precision digits
    dXFDocument.setViewportCenter(0, 0);        
    graphics = dXFDocument.getGraphics();
    mirrorX=1;
    mirrorY=-1;
}

public void addLayer(String layerName, Color c) {
    dXFDocument.setLayer(layerName);      
    graphics.setColor(c);//This will only achieve that the drawing entities get this color, but the layer's color would not be touched.      
}
public void drawLine(double[]x, double[]y){
     if (x!=null&&y!=null&x.length==y.length) {
        for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            graphics.drawLine(mirrorX*x[i-1], mirrorY*y[i-1],mirrorX*x[i],mirrorY*y[i]);
        }
    }
}
public void drawPoint(double[]x, double[]y){
    if (x!=null&&y!=null&x.length==y.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            graphics.drawPoint(mirrorX*x[i], mirrorY*y[i]);
        }
    }
}
public void drawRect(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
    graphics.drawRect(mirrorX*x1, mirrorY*y1, mirrorX*x2, mirrorY*y2);
}

public void saveToDXF(String outputPath) throws IOException {
    String stringOutput = dXFDocument.toDXFString();
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputPath);
    fileWriter.write(stringOutput);
    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

And here is an example code to test it:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String outputFile="d:\\test.dxf";
    int points=500;//Number of drawn points .
    String layer1Name="Layer_1";
    double[]xCoordinatesOfPoints1=new double[points];//creating first test-pointset_Xcoordinates
    double[]yCoordinatesOfPoints1=new double[points];//creating first test-pointset_Ycoordinates
    for (int i = 0; i < xCoordinatesOfPoints1.length; i++) {
        xCoordinatesOfPoints1[i]=i;
        yCoordinatesOfPoints1[i]=i;
    }                
    String layer2Name="Layer_2";
    double[]xCoordinatesOfPoints2=new double[points];//creating second test-pointset_Xcoordinates
    double[]yCoordinatesOfPoints2=new double[points];//creating second test-pointset_Ycoordinates
    for (int i = 0; i < xCoordinatesOfPoints1.length; i++) {
        xCoordinatesOfPoints2[i]=-1*i;
        yCoordinatesOfPoints2[i]=i;
    }
     
    DXFHandler dXFHandler=new DXFHandler(); //Creating dxf handler object        
    dXFHandler.addLayer(layer1Name, Color.red);//Creating layer1
    dXFHandler.drawPoint(xCoordinatesOfPoints1, yCoordinatesOfPoints1);//drawing points of layer1
    dXFHandler.addLayer(layer2Name, Color.GREEN);//Creating layer2
    dXFHandler.drawPoint(xCoordinatesOfPoints2, yCoordinatesOfPoints2);//drawing points of layer2
    try {
        dXFHandler.saveToDXF(outputFile);//Exporting dxf file
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("FAILED");
    }
            
}
```

As a result I get a "test.dxf" file which has a green and red point-set. That would be fine but both layers' default color is white. I would prefer if the points' color was "ByLayer" and the layer color was green/red, as it is in my "wantedSolution.dxf", which I failed to see how to attach. I will attach it as soon as I figure out how to do that...

Comment: Did you ever arrive at a solution to this? I'm sitting with the exact same question :)

Comment: Part-1:
To answer your question I have good news and bad news. :) BAD news is that NO, I have not solved it just yet, as I had other projects and this issue did not have a top priority in my work.
BUT - and this is the GOOD news -  since than in connection with another task I recognized that there might have been some improvements in jdxf since then (or I just missed it before, I don't know), because if you open this link https://jsevy.com/wordpress/index.php/java-and-android/jdxf-java-dxf-library/jdxf-user-guide/ and read the chapter "Layer", it says that this can be done from version 2.0+.

Comment: Part-2:
I am sure I was using older version and I have not yet checked it out if it works or not, BUT even if You (or We) won't find it useful, I'm quite optimistic that it can be done just by examining the Autodesk documentation of dxf format: (https://damassets.autodesk.net/content/dam/autodesk/www/developer-network/platform-technologies/autocad-dxf-archive/acad_r12_dxf.pdf#page=4&zoom=100,92,4769)

Comment: Part-3:
In my other task I mentioned, I needed to open a dxf file, add other drawings to it, then save and close. After some google search I decided to do the coding by myself just by taking a look at the autodesk document (I did not read through all the 59 pages, just the structure of the dxf file itself at pages 4-5 and maybe the UCS section). After that I managed to do a test file manually to use it as a "sample", and after another day of coding and debugging, I managed to reproduce the same sample by my code.

Comment: Part-4(last): In this case, I think we should set somehow the color code in the Layer properties of TABLES section. Sorry for lots of comments, I needed to separate it to be short enough for StachOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

As per your suggestions. Version 2.0 of jDXF allows to set the layer color. Albeit in a strange way. Here's [their guidance](https://jsevy.com/wordpress/index.php/java-and-android/jdxf-java-dxf-library/jdxf-user-guide/).

Essentially it comes down to setting the color and pen width and setting `setPenByLayer` to true.

Code sample from the docs:

```
DXFDocument dxfDocument = new 
    DXFDocument("Example");
DXFGraphics dxfGraphics =
    dxfDocument.getGraphics();

// set pen characteristics to be used for layer
graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
graphics.setColor(Color.RED);

// set layer; will be assigned the current 
// color/linewidth of graphics (red, 2)
dxfDocument.setLayer("Layer 1");

// now set all subsequently drawn objects 
// to take on the pen of their layer, not the
// graphics at the time they are drawn
dxfDocument.setPenByLayer(true);

// oval will have color/pen of Layer 1 (red, 2)
// in the DXF output
graphics.drawOval(500, 500, 150, 150);
// change pen color and draw;
// since the rectangle is going on Layer 1
// and setPenByLayer is true, it will appear
// red in the DXF image since it takes the
// color of its layer
graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
graphics.drawRect(1000, 500, 150, 150);

// turn off the ByLayer flag; subsequent objects
// will be given the current color/style, not 
// that of their layer; the oval will be blue
dxfDocument.setPenByLayer(false);
graphics.drawOval(1000, 500, 150, 150);
```